# How to add column in a DataFrame with some static values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL DataFrame with few columns, but i want to add few more columns in that DataFrame with some static values. How can i do that?

I tried `withColumn` method , but its expecting `Column`

**Expected is:**

```
df.withColumn(col("newColumn", "static value")
```

**Update:**

I got the answer, we need to use `lit` for this purpose.

FOr example:

```
df.withColumn("newColumn", lit("some value")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create it simply using UDF so you can define UDF which return default value and then add column and set default values as follows

```
val defaultValue=spark.udf.register("defaultValue",()=>"default")

df.withColumn(col("newColumn", defaultValue)

df.show()
```